# deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable returns NO in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am trying to use some CoreLocation features, and I am running into problems with deferred location updates.

For some reason when the app was updated for iOS 10 deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable returns NO always.  I am testing on an iPhone 6s, so I know that the device is capable of using GPS features.

I tried using this to debug:

```
[CLLocationManager deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable]
```

I can't figure out if this is an issue with iOS 10 or if I have something set incorrectly.

In this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.deferringUpdates = NO;
    NSLog(@"DEFERRING Error: [%@]", error);
    if (error) {
        [[LocationManagerClient alertWithMessage:error.localizedDescription andTitle:error.domain] show];
    }
}
```

I end up logging this error:

```
DEFERRING Error: [Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=11 "(null)"]
```

Has anyone else run into this problem with iOS 10 or have any idea what is going on?

Edit:
This is how I am setting the distance filter

```
- (void)configureForApplicationWillResignActive {
    [_locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
    [_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];   // use distance filter
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

- (void)configureForApplicationDidBecomeActive {
    [_locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
    [_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];   // use distance filter
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Comment: Have you set a distance filter other than 0?  This will cause error 11. Can you show how you have initialised your CLLocationManager?

Comment: Edited for more detail.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem, calling [CLLocationManager deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable] always returns NO on iOS 10 on our iPhone 6s and 6 devices. Activating deferred location updates causes kCLErrorDomain Code=11

Comment: Same problem for me, iPhone 6S with 10.0.2. Very frustrating, because I had spent many days on getting deferred updates right. Did you report it as a bug?

Comment: We are seeing the same issue in our apps, deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable() always returns false under iOS 10.0.2 and activating deferred locations causes didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError to be called with kCLErrorDeferredFailed - I filed a radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4927958787555328

Comment: Has anyone tried on iOS 11?

Comment: Tried, not working in iOS 11.

Comment: is it working at iOS11.2? I'm still struggling with it.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already filed a Radar (28303779) with proof of concept [sample code](https://github.com/zakishaheen/deferred-location-implementation) - also contains the wording from the radar. I have also opened a [dev forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62863) and it appears a lot of engineers are facing the same problem. `deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable()` is also returning false in iOS 10. Seems like apple has intentionally turned off the functionality.

**Update**

My Bug Report got closed saying 'it works as intended'. I suppose Apple does not intend to fix it and it was mistakenly taken out without deprecation first.

Comment: I also filed a Radar, and my bug report was also closed with the same message from Apple.  This is frustrating.

Comment: @erik I feel you. Already working on an alternate implementation around DLU :(

Answer (score 2):

Deferred updates are now officially deprecated (in iOS 13). This is effectively an admission that they have not been supported for several years.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like this is a bug in iOS 10

We should all file radars to get it fixed, please dupe mine: [openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4927958787555328](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4927958787555328)

Comment: My Bug Report got closed saying 'it works as intended'. I suppose Apple does not intend to fix it and it was mistakenly taken out without deprecation first.

Comment: mine was marked as duplicate of 28561857 and will be closed - too bad that there is no information about 28561857 available :/

Comment: Now it's the same for me: my own report is closed, but marked as duplicate of 28561857, which itself however is still open. I wonder whether any reasoning will also be forwarded to us when they close 28561857.
I can hardly believe that they deliberately removed the feature altogether without deprecating it first or at least mentioning it in any kind of release notes.

Comment: yeah, especially since it looks like Apple cares a lot about energy efficiency and deferred location updates was a great feature

Comment: It is neither fixed in iOS 10.1.1 nor did they close the original bug report - it still says "Duplicate of 28561857 (Open)" in my own (closed) bug report.

Comment: Still not fixed in 10.2.

Comment: 10.3, still not fixed

Comment: Not fixed in iOS 11

Comment: I am beginning to wonder whether they simply decided to use the motion coprocessor for other tasks. So maybe it will only return on a future device which has a more powerful one? Did anyone try on the latest iPhones 8/X?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a "bug". (reproduced on iOS11 and iOS12, iPhone 7, iPad mini 4 cellular)

CLLocationManager.deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable() always returns false, so code for deferred updates never run. However, when app is in the background and Location manager delivers positions via locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]), those positions are delayed as if deferred mode was enabled.

I am thinking that deferred API is there just for compatibility reasons with old apps, and new apps don't need to worry about it at all.

Comment: on which iOS version you have tested? I am using `iPhone SE` with `iOS 12.3.1` and it seems that `deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable()` is returning false.

Comment: tested on iOS11 and iOS12. I am not using deferred updates now, and quite frankly I don't miss them.